# Getting pyinstaller .exe program to run from clicking file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I have a command line based program that I've turned into an executable using PyInstaller. I would like the program to launch a command prompt and run when clicked. Currently I can only get it to run from the command prompt. When I click it, a blank command prompt will open, remain open for a couple of seconds and then close. I'm stuck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `--console` flag with pyinstaller?